# what's the difference about fib function with template?

Tags: c++, templates, fibonacci

here is my code:

```cpp
template<int x>
struct factorial
{
    enum :unsigned long long{ value = x * factorial<x - 1>::value };
};

template<>
struct factorial<1>
{
    enum :unsigned long long{ value = 1 };
};
```

what's the difference between

```cpp
struct factorial<1>
{
    enum :unsigned long long{ value = 1 };
};
```

and

```cpp
struct factorial<0>
{
    enum :unsigned long long{ value = 1 };
};
```

what's the different If i replace 0 with 1？
I try them on my machine and cppinsight ,there is no difference and work find ,but the cw say:

```sh
fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
    enum :unsigned long long{ value = x * factorial<x - 1>::value };
                                          ^
main.cpp:8:43: note: in instantiation of template class 'factorial<-1024>' requested here
main.cpp:8:43: note: in instantiation of template class 'factorial<-1023>' requested here
main.cpp:8:43: note: in instantiation of...
```

the question is from here:https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a74a94f5084d72c710000de/discuss

Comment: _"but the cw say"_ What is a cw? Please provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Take a piece of paper and perform the recursion there. Not a C++ problem but an algorithmic one.

Comment: If you replace `0` with `1`, and then instatiate the template with `0`, there is nothing that stops it from running into all the negative numbers. If you instatiate it with a number `> 0` it should still work fine.

Comment: BTW, factorial of 0 should be `1`, not `0 * ..`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide specialization for `factorial<0>`, it would take definition of primary template, so to instantiate `factorial<0>`; you have to compute:

```
0 * factorial<0 - 1>::value;
```

which will also have to compute `factorial<-1>::value`, so `factorial<-2>::value` and so on...

Once in happen at `factorial<-1024>`, limit of your compiler for recursion is reached, and it stops with the given error.

Comment: Thank you, my question is, why is it still counting 0, shouldn’t it stop after reaching 1, and what is the termination condition of this template?

Comment: for example ,this question have some code not set the fac<0>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098061/meaning-of-factorialt-1-in-template-definition
and in my mechine ,there is no warning and error happen with the code
template<>
struct factorial<1>,and no factorial<0> be writeen.

Comment: "my  machine" means msvc and clang++，sorry for my poor english..

Comment: `factorial<42>` or any positive numbers is fine (with limit recursion), and will indeed stop recursion at `factorial<1>`.

Comment: `factorial<0>` makes sense, it is 1 by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_zero). it is an edge case not handled correctly with your implementation.

Comment: @ffxxee It does stop when reaching `1`. But if you start it at `0` it will go negative. The question says **Test input: non-negative integers x up to 20.**. 0 is a non-negative number up to 20.

Comment: I have seen many places with 0 as the boundary
So I want to know if there is any problem with 1 as the boundary

http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~xyfeng/teaching/FOPL/lectureNotes/MetaprogrammingCpp.pdf
page.4

Comment: @ffxxee You could add a `static_assert` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/c84j71) to get a nice compilation error message if someone tries to use it with negative numbers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for helping me learn how to debug template functions

Comment: @ffxxee You're welcome. It had some unneeded parts there though. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/WTcMaa) would be a simpler version.